# Android LIst view

Tags: android

HI all,

First of all i want to know that what are the index of list view items??? is something like the index of array (a[0],a[1]....).

Actually i want to get the index of list item. it always showing me -1 
here is the code.

```
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {  
      super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);  

      Object index = getListAdapter().getItem(position);

      Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, newsdisplay.class);
      //Create the view using FirstGroup's LocalActivityManager  
      View view = newsgroup.group.getLocalActivityManager()  
            .startActivity("show_city", myIntent  
            .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP))  
            .getDecorView();  

      //Again, replace the view  
      newsgroup.group.replaceView(view);  
 }
```

pls help me how to get the index of list view items and is this unique to other items??

Answer (score 1):

There are two different numbers associated with each item in the listView.

The `position` is the location of the item within the arrayAdapter.

The `index` is the location of the item within the visible ListView items.

Thus, for any given item, the `position` should stay constant over time, but the `index` will change as different items are visible.

It is not clear what you are trying to do with your code snippet, but the Object you call `index` should be the object at `position` within your ArrayAdapter, so `a[position]`.

If the `index` of an item is -1, I would think that would mean it is not currently visible on the screen..